# Extend WiFi range wireless Access Point with outdoor antenne

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a problem with my WiFi range. The signal from the AP in my Office is to low.
I have a TP-Link 300Mbps Advanced Wireless N AP http://www.amazon.de/TP-Link-TL-WA901ND-300Mbps-Wireless-Access/dp/B002YETVXC/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1333722492&sr=1-1.
I supplied it through a PoE injector.

I bought 2 8dBi TP-Link Indoor Omni-directional Antenna (2.4GHz 8dBi Indoor Omni-directional Antenna, Model no. TL-ANT2408CL) , and i changed 2 from the AP antennas, but nothing happened. The signal is the same.

Now I took a Outdoor antenna (something like this: http://www.amazon.de/TP-Link-Netz-Antenne-12dBi-outdoor/dp/B001VG1QGO/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1333722143&sr=8-4) and I am thinking to use it like the 3th antenna.!!!! (If you think I am crazy, is OK!)!

Questions:

1. What is the best way to have a better WiFi range?
2. Should be all 3 Antennas the same to work well?
3. Will work Outdoor antenna indoor? Can my AP work with the BIG Outdoor Antenna without damaging itself?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are your PCs equipped with Wireless N adapters - otherwise you are not taking advantage of the capabilities of your AP. You can provide better coverage by using more APs - if necessary some can be configured as repeaters (not ideal). Your AP will work better if the antennas are the same - and you are unlikely to notice much difference between an 8dBi and 12dBi omni. Directional antennas can work well if you can segment the area and use multiple APs. As you use higher gain antennas you should really consider not exceeding the maximum eirp for your location - 100 mW eirp for europe - although this will only be an issue if you start interfering with another network.

Comment: I have a Intel PRO/Wireless LAN abgn in both Notebooks. But anyway, I never get 300Mbps. It shows 150Mbps near the AP and 15 - 56Mbps in my office. And I use my iPad 2. And here is the problem. It have very poor signal or nothing in my office.